# How to get the result of my query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

So I am trying to query my SAP software database (Oracle apparently) with Excel VBA so I can get result of my queries in a worksheet.

That's what I have done so far :

```vb
Option Explicit 

Private LogonControl As SAPLogonCtrl.SAPLogonControl 
Private ConnexionSAP As SAPLogonCtrl.Connection 
Private TableFactory As SAPTableFactory 

Public Functions As SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctions 

Dim objBAPIControl, objgetaddress As Object 
Dim vLastRow, vRows As Integer 
Dim vcount_add, index_add As Integer 
Dim rng As Range 


Public objaddress, objkunnr As SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Table 
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer() 

Dim dbs As DAO.Database 
Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset 
Dim strSQL As String 
Dim sht As Worksheet 

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 


Dim retcd        As Boolean 
Dim SilentLogon  As Boolean 


Set LogonControl = CreateObject("SAP.LogonControl.1") 
Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") 
Set ConnexionSAP = LogonControl.NewConnection 


ConnexionSAP.Client = "100" 
ConnexionSAP.ApplicationServer = "x.x.x.x" 
ConnexionSAP.Language = "EN" 
ConnexionSAP.User = "uid" 
ConnexionSAP.Password = "pwd" 
ConnexionSAP.System = "xxx" 
ConnexionSAP.SystemNumber = "00" 
ConnexionSAP.UseSAPLogonIni = False 

SilentLogon = False 
retcd = ConnexionSAP.Logon(0, SilentLogon) 

If retcd = True Then MsgBox "Log OK" 
If retcd <> True Then MsgBox "Logon failed": Exit Sub 


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" 
Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot) 

sht.Cells(1, 2) = "RESULT HERE" 

End Sub
```

Running this code gives me an error at the last lines of the code :

> Object variable or With block variable not set

How can I get the result of my query (to get all my db tables information) in the cell ' B1 ' ?

Comment: As with pretty every single instance of run-time error 91, you're making a member call against an object variable that was never initialized. Can you spot it? What's the reference `dbs` is assigned to? That's right - `Nothing`.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I've done this to correct : added `Set dbs = CurrentDb`
now I've got : "runtime error 424 : object required" , it seems that `CurrentDb` is not OK with the connection with SAP application I've done before and cannot recognize the db..?

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top, and declare every variable you're using. There's nothing called `CurrentDb` in Excel. What's `dbs` supposed to be connecting to? Do you have a connection string? Also, consider using ADODB instead of DAO, which is pretty much only used within Access.